# Sharepoint Query returns no results for with >5000 items

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-rest-api

When I go to a specific folder in Sharepoint, I hit an error that I have exceeded the view threshold of 5000 items. I created a new view to only show items when the ID < 5000, I am able to see the folder contents now.

However, how do I apply a specific view/filter when using Python?

Using Python's request module, I have:

```
requestUrl = sharePointUrl + "/{0}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/{0}/{1}')/Files".format(site, folder)
headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json; odata=verbose', 'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'}
requests.get(requestUrl , headers=headers).json()
```

which returns `{'d': {'results': []}}`

If I modify the requestUrl to include `?$top=1000` or `?$filter=Id lt 1000`, I still have an empty result (no throttled error, just empty result)

How do I apply the filters correctly or use a specific view when running the request query?

(I used a different folder name and I get an error `'Field or property "Id" does not exist.'` so clearly something is wrong with my query too but I am not sure why the other folder returns empty result and not an error)

Answer (score 0):

just having a first glance on it and looking at this line

```
requestUrl = sharePointUrl + "/{0}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/{0}/{1}')/Files".format(site, folder)
```

it will seem like the URL you want to create might be wrong. I think you should not add `site` to the `GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl` as you already will be running this in the context of the site. So for example if your site is `sites/someSite` and folder is `shared documents` you will have

```
sites/someSite/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/someSite/shared documents')/Files
```

but I think you should have something like

```
sites/someSite/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('shared documents')/Files
```

could you give it a double check?

Comment: That syntax is correct (it is how it's setup)